# nested tables columns equal width

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, nested, css-tables

I have a nested table and here's a working demo,

http://jsfiddle.net/ZWdA3/

```
<table class="table">
<tr class="accordion-toggle"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#test">
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>1337</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
    <td>Some text</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="test">
    <table class="table"><tr><td>Some text</td>
    <td>1337</td>
    <td>Some text 354325252352352</td>
    <td>Some text</td></tr>
     </table>
    </div>
</tr>
```

It works fine but I need to have the child table columns to have the same width as the parent table.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In case you really want to use tables for this case, you should set the table layout to fixed and set the column width for both the parent and child tables.

```css
.table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 600px;
}

.table > tr > td {
    width: 150px;
}
```

See your [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZWdA3/9/).